# Retrieving the data binding value inside Iframe in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, iframe

I am trying to load an external page inside my angular template. However i need to pass the sess_id value along with the url for the authentication purpose. I have added a iframe inside my div and called the url along with the sess_id value. the sess_id value is retrieved properly inside my modal. but i could not load the page inside Iframe.

My url structure to be retrieved should be like "urlhere?ss_id=bfc443c761de8b2ba18c82fecc50fd77"

```
  <section class="panel panel-default" data-ng-controller="loginController">
        <div class="panel-body" style=" position: relative;">
            <div id="report_loader" style="min-height:600px;">
            {{sess_id}} // i can retrive the value here
        <iframe ng-src="{{ 'urlhere?ss_id=' + sess_id }}"> </iframe>
            </div>
        </div>
  </section>
```

Any Help will be highly appresiated.

Comment: show an example of a full url

Answer (score 0):

Use directive

```
angular.module('testModule').directive('iframeDr', function ($compile) {
return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    //terminal:true,
    link: function(scope, element, attr)  {
        var tryme = scope.sess_id
        var ele = $compile('<iframe ng-src="urlhere?ss_id={{'+tryme+'}}"> </iframe>')(scope);
        element.replaceWith(ele);
    }
}
```

})

and add the directive to your iframe

```
<iframe ng-src="{{ 'urlhere?ss_id=' + sess_id }}" iframe-dr></iframe>
```